# Does any one knows how to get sql statement in ado.net entity

Tags: ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

How to get the exact sql query which is genarting at time of domaincontext.submitchanges() as i am getting validation error and not able to find where is the exact issues

Does any one knows how to get sql statement in ado.net entity

Comment: I am getting error on submitchanges while trying to insert new record, i want to get sql query generated by entitysql to pass to database for final execution.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you at least know what technology are you using. EF 4.1 doesn't have any `SubmitChanges` but Linq-to-Sql does.

How to get executed SQL in Linq-to-Sql: Use [Log property](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/profiling_linq_to_sql_using_th.html) or external profiler.

How to get executed SQL in EF: [Use external profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you have parameters I don't think you can do it directly. You would need to cast everything to a string and build it yourself. I suppose being able to intercept the exact SQL statement going through the pipes is a security risk. At least that's the conclusion I came to when I tried to print the SQL statement I was sending out.

Comment: Just to clearify, we are adding one entity object via addobject method of domain service class and after add called submitchanges.     and here entity sql must be creating statment like insert into tbl (a,b) i want to know about this